# ListView custom layout

Tags: android, performance

In the ListView im fetching user comments from my web API as JSON.

In my custom layout I added an ImageView which is *optionally*, because it only appears when the user has post an image.

Is it good **as performance** to use an empty ImageView in my layout with an ID? When the URL for image is empty it won't happen something, but when it contains an URL, I will change the image resource to the bitmap with an image loader library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a default image if at all there is no image returned in your JSON response. Else you can also hide the visibility of imageview by,

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE) 
}
```

Also since you are using a listview even if there are too many items, since the same views will be reused there will be no much memory and performance issues.